# Update counter in map function and access in reduce

Tags: hadoop

I am using Hadoop Pipes. I want to use counter in map which should be accessible in reduce function.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, within the same job that is not possible. However, you can have a single job without a reducer, collect whatever counter information you would like to compute, then start a second job where you add those counted values in the job configuration object and the reducer of the second job can then access those values.

Edit:

Here is a code example:

```
enum COUNTERS {C1; C2;}

class DriverCode
{
  Configuration conf = new Configuration();
  //the Mapper increases C1
  Job job1 = new Job(conf, "Job1"); 
  job1.setJarByClass(MyJar.class);
  job1.setMapperClass(MyMapper1.class); 
  ...

  //read out C1 
  long c1 = job.getCounters().findCounter(COUNTERS.C1).getValue();

  //set it for the new job
  conf.setLong("c1",c1);
  Job job2 = new Job(conf, "Job2"); 
  //and now you can access this configuration object in your second job
  job2.setJarByClass(MyJar.class); 
  job2.setMapperClass(MyMapper2.class);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to write the program without reducer? And how I can pass values to reducer of the next job?

Comment: Can anybody answer the previous comment, please?